# How to adjust ConstraintLayout height with Recyclerview's height?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to have a recycler view with list of things of unknown number and a button below the RecyclerView. I want the height of the whole ConstraintLayout be flexible with the height of my RecyclerView, i.e. if the list is short, wrap content and if the list is long, just fill up the whole screen.
Now no matter how long the list is, the ConstraintLayout will fill up the whole screen . I have already had everything wrap_content but there is still blank space at bottom.I want my button always appear on the bottom.  Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Hi @sherrygeek you need to share the code for the same your layout xml atleast and your recyclerView row(item) xml

Comment: Please share the relevant code to show your work

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to achieve this:

Your constraint layout will be the parent (root) with match parent for both width and height so it will take the whole screen.

Then put the button, the left and right sides should connect to the constraint layout sides, and the bottom of the button should connect with the bottom of the layout too (3 constraints only: right to right, left to left and bottom to bottom). Wrap content for both width and height.

The recyclerView will connect almost the same, top to top, left to left and right to right with the constraintLayout, but the bottom should connect with the top of your button. Finally select match parent for both width and weight.

On this way, your button will be always at the bottom of the screen and the recycler view height will go from top of the screen to top of your button.

If you want to change the constraints of your layout accordingly to some conditions (like reach specific number of items on your list) you need to do it programmatically.

Select by default your recycler view height as wrap_content, and on code write a method which observe every time an item is added or removed from your list. Create a conditional which says if the recyclerView.count( )== number and if it is true change the constraintLayout and child's constraints with something like this (example):

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
constraintSet.connect(R.id.recycler,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.button,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
 constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```